# jsPDF not defined Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to use the jspdf-autotable module which I installed via

`npm install jspdf jspdf-autotable`

To use the module in my Ionic component I did the following:

```
declare let jsPDF;
```

I then proceed with some sample code taken from the jspdf-autotable repo in my component:

```
  createReport() {
    let columns = ["ID", "Name", "Age", "City"]
    let data = [
      [1, "Jonathan", 25, "Gothenburg"],
      [2, "Simon", 23, "Gothenburg"],
      [3, "Hanna", 21, "Stockholm"]
    ]
    let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    doc.autoTable(columns, data);
    doc.save("table.pdf");
  }
```

upon calling createReport() I get the following error message however:   `ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined`

How can I correctly import jspdf-autotable? Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the plugin and declare jsPDF as a global variable in your component.

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'

declare var jsPDF: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jraspante, however I get the following error using WebStorm: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'jsPDF'

Comment: Try removing the global declaration

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'
import 'jspdf-autotable'
```

For some reason only specifying rows and columns as follows would work:

```
var columns = [
    {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
    {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"}, 
    {title: "Country", dataKey: "country"}, 
    ...
];
var rows = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Shaw", "country": "Tanzania", ...},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Nelson", "country": "Kazakhstan", ...},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Garcia", "country": "Madagascar", ...},
    ...
];
```